# Problemas com configuração de tabelas em PrimeFaces

Tags: css, jsf-2.2, primefaces-3.5

Saudação para todos,
sou novo como programador Java, e estou tendo dificuldade de configurar algumas coisas na tabela por falta de experiência, observe a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vocês podem ver o campo Ano de fabrica está mau colocado, ele está assim;

```
Ano de
Fabrica
```

E na verdade deveria está assim;

```
Ano de Fabrica
```

Essa é minha pagina XHTML

```
        <div class="left-sidebar">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel1"
                style="width: 50%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">

                <p:outputLabel value="Tipo" for="tipo" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="tipo">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione o tipo" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel value="Marca" for="marca" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="marca">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a marca" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel value="Modelo" for="modelo" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="modelo">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione o modelo" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:outputLabel value="Preço" for="preco" />
                <p:inputText id="preco" size="20" maxlength="20" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Tamanho" for="tamanho" />
                <p:inputText id="tamanho" size="20" maxlength="20" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Tripulação" for="tripulacao" />
                <p:inputText id="tripulacao" size="20" maxlength="20" />


                <p:outputLabel value="Ano de Fabrica" for="anofabrica" />
                <p:inputText id="anofabrica" size="20" maxlength="20" />

            </p:panelGrid>

        </div>
```

Como faço para fazer as alterações?

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte, recomento sempre usar `<p:row>` e `<p:column>` no `<p:panelGrid>`, caso queira alterar o tamanho da coluna dos Labels mude o `width` no primeiro `<p:column>`. Segue o código:

```
 <p:panelGrid id="painel1"
                 style="width: 50%; margin-top: 20px">

        <p:row>
            <p:column style="width: 90px;">
                <p:outputLabel value="Tipo" for="tipo" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="tipo">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione o tipo" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value="Marca" for="marca" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="marca">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a marca" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value="Modelo" for="modelo" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="modelo">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione o modelo" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value="Preço" for="preco" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="preco" size="20" maxlength="20" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value="Tamanho" for="tamanho" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="tamanho" size="20" maxlength="20" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value="Tripulação" for="tripulacao" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="tripulacao" size="20" maxlength="20" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value="Ano de Fabrica" for="anofabrica" />

            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:inputText id="anofabrica" size="20" maxlength="20" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: foi interessante saber essa informação, mas ainda continua com o mesmo problema.

Comment: no meu funcionou, mas sem columnClasses="rotulo, campo", tente tirar no seu.

Comment: tudo bem, quem bom que funcionou no seu, mas no meu não funcionou, já tentei dá um clear, já reiniciei o servidor tomcat e nada.

Comment: qual sua versão do primefaces?

Comment: A versão de é primefaces 3.5

Comment: deve ser por isso, testei na 5.2. Você não pode atualizar?

Comment: acabei de atualiza, mas não resolveu.

Comment: você alterou o style="width: 90px;" que eu coloquei na primeira coluna? Provavelmente vai ter que colocar um valor maior

Answer (score 0):

Você pode configurar a classe CSS que vc criou:

```
.rotulo { width: 250px; text-align: right }
```

Comment: Ainda não resolveu, a palavra Ano de Fabrica está coloca na mesma posição.

Comment: Eu coloquei  width: 3050px; text-align: right; e não foi movida nada